# SonarQube 5.2 fails to analyze Multi-catch Expression in Java

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

When analyzing a java source file that contains a muli-catch expression, the analysis of the file fails with the error message "Unable to create symbol table".

If I remove the following line:

```
} catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
```

and change it to

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
...
} catch (IOException e) {
```

it works.

The Java plugin has already been updated to the current version 3.8
I start the sonar analysis with the maven plugin, using the last version and Java 8.

Anyone has an idea if this is a bug or if there is a configuration error on my side?

Comment: Could you add to the question the stacktrace which is logged?

Comment: I do not get a stacktrace, I run the analysis with mvn sonar:sonar -X and get the following output:  [ERROR] Unable to create symbol table for : /data/tmp/SonarProblem/sonarproblem/src/main/java/de/linova/ScriptRunner.java  
The analysis itself is marked as successful, it just did not analyse this single file and shows 0 issues for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation, there is an issue in version `3.8` of the `java plugin` regarding semantic analysis and union types. Note that the bug you are facing will only occur as soon as one of the exceptions has a parametrized type as super type, anywhere in its hierarchy, and will cause the analysis of the file to fail.

In your situation, `SQLException` implements `Iterable<Throwable>`, which causes the interruption of the semantic analysis.
When using separated catch clauses, the analysis works fine.

Note that there is **no error of configuration on your side**. Thank you for the reproducer you provided, it helped identifying the problem.

I created the following JIRA ticket to handle the issue: [SONARJAVA-1418](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1418)